# Handling MVC Session for every page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization

In fairly new to MVC and I would like to use a session.  I have a base controller and all my other controller inherit from my base.  I need the session checked every time a page is hit.

What is the best way to go about this?

**Updated**

My session will need to store an id to be able to build the pages correctly.  If the session doesn't have the ID I need to look up the information in DB.  I don't want to use cache because IDs could be different for different users.

Comment: What do you need to check in the session? What functionality is required? Please provide more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going the cache route.

Create a class called 'CacheHelper' and within it, a method called 'GetId()'
In the GetId() method, setup a Dictionary object to store your values and use the username as the key.
Each time you call GetId, check to see if the Key exists in your dictionary

```
myDictionary.ContainsKey(username);
```

If not, look it up in the database, add it to the dictionary, then resave it to cache.